# How to reload a file in vim?

Tags: vim

Various editors like `gedit` detect if the file is changed and asks to reload it. Sometimes in `vim` when I got many files to edit, I sometimes end up opening same file in different tabs for quick look with other files and several other reasons.

So is there anyway I can force to reload the current file before I update anything to it.

I know one option is to exit and reopen it, but I have splitted the screen and I don't want to loose that view.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `:e!` you can reload the same file and dismiss any changes that you did until that point, after the last save.

If you did not do anything in vim, but changed the file externally, you can reload by just type `:e`.